# (lua) What is the role of the parameter t in this search function?

Tags: lua

The following code is a multi-inheritance demo in Programming in Lua.

```lua
local function search(k, plist)
    for i=1, #plist do
        local v = plist[i][k]
        if v then return v end
    end
end 

function createClass(...)
    local c = {}
    local parents = {...}
    -- what's the role of parameter t?
    setmetatable(c, {__index = function (t, k)
        return search(k, parents)
    end})
    c.__index = c
    function c:new(o)
        o = o or {}
        setmetatable(o, c)
        return o
    end
    return c
end
Account = {
    balance = 0,
    withdraw = function (self, v) self.balance = self.balance - v end,
    deposit =function (self, v) self.balance = self.balance + v end,
    getbalance = function (self) return self.balance end,
    new = function (self, v) 
        v = v or {}
        setmetatable(v, self)
        self.__index = self
        return v
    end,
}
Named = {
    name = "",
    getname = function (self) return self.name end,
    setname = function (self, n) self.name = n end,
}
NamedAccount = createClass(Account, Named)
account = NamedAccount:new{name = 'Paul'}
print(account:getname())
account:setname("Phoenix")
print(account:getname())
account:deposit(1000)
print(account:getbalance())
account:withdraw(221)
print(account:getbalance())
```

As is shown in the code above, what is the role of parameter t in the statement `setmetatable(c, {__index = function (t, k) return search(k, parents) end})`. The parameter t doesn't seem to be used. I've tried to delete it, but I got a error message:

> lua: Multi-inheritance.lua:46: attempt to call a nil value (method 'getname')
> stack traceback:
> Multi-inheritance.lua:46: in main chunk
> [C]: in ?

It looks as if I cannot delete it simply. Is there anyone can tell me what the role of t plays here?

Comment: `t` is the object being indexed.  If you don't need it, you may replace it with underscore: `__index = function (_, k)`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff Thank you, I got it.